# How to Create a Menu in Python that runs specific scripts when selected

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, menu, user-input, linux-mint

I'm fairly new to Python and have had an idea but am unsure how to execute it.

**I would like to create a python script that acts as a menu to run other scripts. In the sense that let's say the file is called menu.py. The script would look something like this:**

```
**Menu**

   

     print("Which Script would you like to run")
    #1) Convert.py
    #2) Analyse.py
    #3) Visualise.py

#when selecting 1,2 or 3, the specified script is run.
#after selection it reads "You selected *script*" and then runs the selected script
```

I have researched and found basic menus in python that run print statements upon selection but nothing such like running a script when selected. I have seen examples such as:

```
menu = {}
menu['1']="Add Student." 
menu['2']="Delete Student."
menu['3']="Find Student"
menu['4']="Exit"
while True: 
  options=menu.keys()
  options.sort()
    for entry in options: 
      print entry, menu[entry]

    selection=raw_input("Please Select:") 
    if selection =='1': 
      print "add" 
    elif selection == '2': 
      print "delete"
    elif selection == '3':
      print "find" 
    elif selection == '4': 
      break
    else: 
      print "Unknown Option Selected!"
```

But it doesn't run scripts more so, print statements.

I'm using Python3 and VisualStudioCode on Linux Mint.

Any advice to point in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use executable directories with [`__main__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#main-py-in-python-packages) so that for an app called `eDir` your structure (on Windows) would be smth like

```py
C:
├───eDir
│   │   scr1.py
│   │   scr2.py
│   │   __main__.py
```

- In `__main__.py` you could have

```py
print("MAIN MENU".center(80, "—"))
print("1. Blue")
print("2. Red")
selection = input("~~> Chose Your Destiny (Blue/Red):")
if selection == "Blue":
    import scr1
elif selection == "Red":
    import scr2
```

- imported modules execute upon import so just for this example we are not using any functions and demo with a simple `print` statement

```
#scr1.py
print("Enjoy your Illusion")
#scr2.py
print("Welcome to the Matrix.")
```

- then, call the folder from the outside
- what happens is that a directory that is being "executed" is first added to `sys.path`
- this way, `__main__.py` can easily import any other modules with which it shares a directory
- in this way, the directory can be conceptualized as a program

```
▶ C:\python eDir
———————————————————————————————————MAIN MENU————————————————————————————————————
1. Blue
2. Red
~~> Chose Your Destiny (Blue/Red):Blue
Enjoy your Illusion
```